# How can remove duplicate value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a some data stored in $data[], there are some items in it. How do I remove duplicate values in a foreach?

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC
)
Array
(
    [0] => XZY
)
Array
(
    [0] => ABC
)
```

i have use some function array unique and convert it to json ... and not work

Comment: Post the code pls.

Comment: Please add the code and provide more details in order to investigate the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Please read that link and make sure that the code you post in your question is minimal (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), complete (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and verifiable (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). JsFiddle links don't count as an MCVE. Without an MCVE in your question, this question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: i do not understand how update issue i create new post see here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407050/how-remove-duplicate-value-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_unique($array)` function in order to remove duplicate value. It takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.

Comment: What you want to achieve? Can you send me your code or script? I will do and let you know.

Comment: i think because i'am in a loop this is my code :
`code`
$cache = [];
  for($i=0;$i<=count(get_numerics($name));$i++){
 $cc = get_numerics($name);
 $num = $cc[$i];
 $cc = validatefunc($num);
 if (is_numeric($cc)) {
 if(trueresult($cc)) {
 if (!in_array($cc, $cache)){
        $cache[] = $cc;
}
} 
}

}

Comment: @Zimo - Provide your array input and expected output so I can do as per your requirements. This code isn't be identify properly.

Comment: @Zimo please update your question with your code because we don't know what does your `get_numerics()`, `validatefunc()` and `trueresult()` functions. This answer is the correct one for the question you asked so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **array_merge()** first. Then on result do **array_unique();**

Comment: i try this code and not work :
$arrmerg = array_merge($cache);
$unique=array_unique($arrmerg);
print_r($unique);

Comment: post the code you're currently working with. Can't help with it not completely posted.

Comment: btw, array_merge uses two paramaters : array_merge($array1, $array2);

Comment: but i have only one array $data

Answer (score 0):

$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));